# How to get aerospike data backup in .json format?

Tags: aerospike

I want to take Aerospike data backup in .json format.

Backup will be done periodically using timestamp parameter and c# windows service.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working for you? Besides, why json? This is a database, not a single text file, AFAIK.

Comment: Ptaq666, I know that its database but i want to take Aerospike data backup in every 15minute by windows service. After that i will read each .json file and work on that data

Answer (score 2):

As for the time being the only supported format is text format as mentioned in aerospike [documentation](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-tools-backup/tree/master#backup-file-format).

Although one way around it is to backup the file in text format and use some tool to parse it to `JSON`. Here is a spark/scala example since the I had a really huge and it made sense to use spark in my case but you can achieve the same with the same result programmatically using other techniques.

```
val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job().getConfiguration
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "+ n namespace")

val rawRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile( "/path/to/file", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf).map{ case (_, v) => v.toString }

val rdds = rawRDD.map(x => {
  val record = x.split('\n')
  var key = ""
  var value = ""
  for (line <- record){
    if(line.trim().startsWith("- S key ") ){
      key = line.split("- S key ")(1).split(' ')(1)
    } else if(line.trim().startsWith("- S value ") ){
      value = line.split("- S value ")(1).split(' ')(1)
    }
  }
  (key,value)
})
```

**Note**: The above code above to demonstrate how to parse the text file and it's not production grade code so it can easily break and can't cover edge cases. you still need to transform the RDDs to JSON afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on the data in the backups produced by [asbackup](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/backup/asbackup.html), you should parse the .asb data files it outputs.

Each record is saved on a separate line, and there's a very clear specification for the [backup file format](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-tools-backup/tree/master#backup-file-format). You can easily find out the data type of each of the bins (fields) of the record.

Comment: That's not true, if you check the documentation you'll see that each record spans multi-lines., here is a sample https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-tools-backup/tree/master#sample-backup-file

Comment: Ha, you’re right. I meant to say that the record’s data is contiguous, but it is multiline.